# Search Algorithm for Pacman

Tags: c, assembly, path-finding, pacman

I need to find the path with the lower cost in a graph represented by a matrix. I researched a bit on the Dijkstra's algorithm but I need a vector with the sequence of nodes in the shortest path, not the distance itself. The game is being made ​​for Assembly, but if anyone knows an implementation in C at least it's gonna help a lot. I will use it to calculate the route of ghosts, matching heuristic algorithms to create the Very Hard Mode of the game. I also tried something with A*, but the implementations I found used struct, which are not applicable to the situation. Thanks a lot since now. ^^

Comment: When you calculate the newest shortest distance, can't you simply associate the node with the information of the predecessor? Then one needs to backtrack / reverse the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is the basis for the [edx AI course](https://www.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS188.1x/2013_Spring/about). I've managed to google a [breadth first search](http://www.rdaemon.com/home/breadth-first-search) code written in C here. From what I can remember breadth first search is guarenteed to find the shortest path if it exists.
I don't think it would be too hard to add a heuristic algorithm in there either, there should be notes on the edx link that would help with that.